# Best way to handle , delete in linklist while traversing it

Tags: pointers, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Suppose I have a Singly link list, I am traversing it and calling some function f() to delete some element on some condition.that function can delete multiple elements in the same list,  this can make the pointer we are traversing invalid....

What is the best possible approach to handle this type of scenario..

Comment: Use 2 pointers together, once for deleting and other for address of adjacent element

Answer (score 0):

Indeed when you delete a node in a singly linked list, the reference (pointer) you have to that deleted node becomes invalid as soon as you free the corresponding memory.

As a side note: in some programming languages this is never an issue, as they do the memory management for you, making it impossible to have a reference to freed memory (e.g. Java). In those environments, memory is freed when (or some time after) there is no more reference to it.

The general way to deal with this during the list traversal, is to keep a reference to the *next* node in the list. In order to delete the current node, you'll also need to rewire the pointer that refers to it in the previous node. So you'll need three references: previous, current, and next.

Pseudo code:

```
prevptr := NIL
currentptr := headptr
while currentptr != NIL:
    nextptr := currentptr->next
    if decision_to_delete(currentptr):
        if prevptr != NIL:
            prevptr->next := nextptr
        else:
            headptr := nextptr
        dispose_memory(currentptr->)
    else:
        prevptr := currentptr
    currentptr := nextptr
```

If you have a function f() that may delete several *consecutive* nodes, starting from the current one you pass it, then make sure that function *returns* a reference to the first node that it did *not* delete:

```
prevptr := NIL
currentptr := headptr
while currentptr != NIL:
    currentptr := f(currentptr)
    if prevptr != NIL:
        prevptr->next := currentptr 
    else:
        headptr := currentptr
    if currentptr == NIL:
        return
    prevptr := currentptr
    currentptr := currentptr->next
```

In this scenario it is the responsibility of `f` to decide whether to delete nodes (if any) and to dispose of the memory that was occupied by the nodes it deletes. The implementation of `f` would use the nextptr way of working, and so we wouldn't need that separate reference anymore in the calling code.